# how to replace blank values with null in http post body in Jmeter while reading data from csv for multiple iterations?

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I am able to use below code to replace blank value with null in http post request body

```
def body =   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue().replaceAll('""','null')
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()        
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', body,'')        
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

But, I get an error for multiple iterations.
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method getValue() on null object

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the `removeAllArguments` call is affecting subsequent calls to the first line.  If it works the first time and fails all subsequent calls then it's probably that.  Try commenting that line out and see if it continues to happen:

```
def body =   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue().replaceAll('""','null')
sampler.getArguments().removeAllArguments()        // I bet this line affects all invocations of the script.
sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', body,'')        
sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't that be easier to go for [__strReplace() function](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup) instead (can be installed as a part of **Custom JMeter Functions** bundle using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#strReplacesupfont-color-gray-size-1-since-1-4-0-font-sup))?

---

Whatever, if you like Groovy and copy-pasting the code from Internet without understanding what it's doing I think you need to amend "your" code to look like:

```
def data = new org.apache.jmeter.config.Arguments()
def body = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('',sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue().replaceAll('""','null'),'',false)
data.addArgument(body)
sampler.setArguments(data)
```